# How to adjust vertical space between multiple IEEEeqnarray environments?

Tags: luatex, koma-script, ieeetran

Let's say that I have 5 `IEEEeqnarray` environments one after another and the third and fourth environment are inside minipages:

```
%! TEX program = lualatex

\documentclass[fleqn, oneside, titlepage = false, fontsize = 12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{cmun}[
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*rm,
    ItalicFont=*ti,
    BoldFont=*bx,
    BoldItalicFont=*bi,
]

\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}

    \begin{IEEEeqnarray}{c}
        a^2+b^2=c^2
    \end{IEEEeqnarray}

    \begin{IEEEeqnarray}{c}
        a^2+b^2=c^2
    \end{IEEEeqnarray}

    {\centering\begin{minipage}{6cm}
    \begin{IEEEeqnarray}{c}
        a^2+b^2=c^2
    \end{IEEEeqnarray}
    \end{minipage}\par}

    {\centering\begin{minipage}{6cm}
    \begin{IEEEeqnarray}{c}
        a^2+b^2=c^2
    \end{IEEEeqnarray}
    \end{minipage}\par}

    \begin{IEEEeqnarray}{c}
        a^2+b^2=c^2
    \end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

The vertical space between each two environments is different:
[image: Vertical space between multiple environments]

Vertical distance between two environments (from biggest to smallest):

1. Red:

   ```
    IEEEeqnarray
    IEEEeqnarray
   ```
2. Blue:

   ```
    IEEEeqnarray
    IEEEeqnarray inside minipage
   ```
3. Purple:

   ```
    IEEEeqnarray inside minipage
    IEEEeqnarray
   ```
4. Green:

   ```
    IEEEeqnarray inside minipage
    IEEEeqnarray inside minipage
   ```

Is it possible to determine what those lengths are or do I adjust them approximately with `\vskip` until things look "good enough" or something else?

Comment: This looks very odd and like an XY problem. I suspect the issue of irregular spacing could be circumvented by using either `gather` or `align` environments, and then if there is anything you need to place in between use `\intertext` (or a variant thereof).

Comment: I don't think that I'm gonna use those environments like that. They are gonna be separated by some text or show up in consistent groups i.e. 5 IEEEeqnarray environments or 5 IEEEeqnarray environments inside minipages; never a "mixture". My goal is "global" consistency in my document i.e. I wanna figure out how much vspace an IEEEeqnarray adds before/after if the previous/next "object" is/isn't an IEEE environment. The same goes for IEEEeqnarrays inside minipages.

Comment: Let's say that on page 10 of my document I have 3 IEEEeqnarray evironments and on page 20, I have 3 IEEEeqnarray environments inside minipages. The vertical spacing is gonna be consistent locally (the vertical spaing between each environment on page 10 is gonna be the same, the same goes for page 20) but not globally (the vspace between two environments on page 10 is not the same as the vspace between two environments on page 20).